# Routemaster replace is doing push

Tags: flutter, routemaster

[image]

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:routemaster/routemaster.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      late final RoutemasterDelegate _routerDelegate = RoutemasterDelegate(
        routesBuilder: (context) => RouteMap(
          routes: buildRoutingTable(
            routerDelegate: _routerDelegate,
          ),
        ),
      );
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp.router(
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            theme: ThemeData(
              useMaterial3: true,
              colorSchemeSeed: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
            ),
            routeInformationParser: const RoutemasterParser(),
            routerDelegate: _routerDelegate,
          );
    }
    
    Map<String, PageBuilder> buildRoutingTable({
      required RoutemasterDelegate routerDelegate,
    }) =>
        {
          PathConstants.tabContainerPath: () => MaterialPage(
                name: 'first-screen',
                child: FirstScreen(
                  onNavigate: () => routerDelegate.replace(
                    _PathConstants.secondScreen,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          PathConstants.secondScreen: () => const MaterialPage(
                name: 'second-screen',
                child: SecodScreen(),
              ),
        };
    
    class _PathConstants {
      const PathConstants.();
    
      static String get tabContainerPath => '/';
    
      static String get secondScreen => '${tabContainerPath}second-screen';
    }
    
    class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      final VoidCallback onNavigate;
      const FirstScreen({
        Key? key,
        required this.onNavigate,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Fisrt screen'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: onNavigate,
              child: const Text('Replace'),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class SecodScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      const SecodScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Second screen'),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to know about route master? please question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

static String get secondScreen => '${tabContainerPath}second-screen';

should be

static String get secondScreen => '/second-screen';

as an absolute path , in order to make "replace" work.

please refer to the following document.

https://morioh.com/p/016a91402d7b